# Execute command for all rows with equal field content

Tags: awk

I have a student csv file containing fields with student data and the mailadress of the teacher in charge at the end. I try to automatically send only one email to the teacher containing all his students (using sendemail). The mail part is no problem but i cannot get the data out of the csv they way I want it.
The csv file is created daily and contains a different number of students every day.

```
aer,kdx,mail1
dke,kad,mail2
err,qqq,mail1
qpi,bcc,mail1
bkd,onk,mail2
kcc,mnb,mail3
```

I tried to use awk and put all lines containing the same mailadress in an array but failed with that approach.

In this example it should send 3 mails. First containing

```
aer,kdx
err,qqq
qpi,bcc
```

Second containing

```
dke,kad
bkd,onk
```

Third containing

```
kcc,mnb
```

Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` to create 3 files with the respective contents `$1` and `$2` with filename derived from `$3`:

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}{print $1,$2 > $3"_out.csv"}' student.csv
```

Standard `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}{out=$2"_out.csv"; print $1,$2 >> out; close(out)}' student.csv
```

Then loop these files and send your email:

```
for m in *_out.csv; do
    _mail_command_
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The idea is very good. Unfortunately, I get: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
        BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}{print $1,$2 > >>>  $8"_out.csv" <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1

I work on macOS

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for your help! This works perfectly!! I would have never been able to figure that out myself.

Comment: Thanks, Ed! I added your version to my answer if that is ok :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this as:

```
sort -t, -k3,3 student.csv |
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    $3 != prev {
        close(out)
        out = $3 FS "out.csv"
        prev = $3
    }
    { print $1, $2 > out }
' ||
exit 1

for file in *,out.csv; do
    email="${file%,*}"
    send email to "$email" containing "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

command

```
for i in `awk -F "," '{if(!seen[$3]++)print $3}' filename`; do awk -F "," -v  i="$i" '$NF == i{print $1","$2}' filename >$i.csv; mailx -s "suject " -a "$i".csv $i</dev/null;done
```

Tested and worked fine

```
First we collecting unique email id and Fetching students who belongs to that email id and saving in file and sending email
```